# Unknown get_image function error in Timber Twig file

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I am experiencing the following error when trying to display an image gallery Advanced Custom Field's field on my client's website.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unknown "get_image" function.`

I have tried switching the image galleries return format between array, URL, and ID, but the same issue always occurs.

The code that I am using to display the gallery of images is being used in a category Twig file using the following code. Not all story posts have galleries, but the if statement should be handling this I assume.

I copied the gallery output code directly from the Timber documentation site.

Timber is up to date using 1.18.2.

```
{% if story.meta( 'photo_gallery' ) %}
  {% for image in story.meta( 'photo_gallery' ) %}
  <img src="{{ get_image(image) }}" />
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s actually an error in the documentation. The `get_image()` function is a function from the [upcoming 2 version of Timber](https://github.com/timber/timber/releases/tag/2.0.0-alpha.1), but shouldn’t be listed in the documentation for version 1.

It should work if you use `Image()` instead of `get_image()`:

```
{% if story.meta( 'photo_gallery' ) %}
  {% for image in story.meta( 'photo_gallery' ) %}
      <img src="{{ Image(image) }}" />
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I’ll check if I can get the documentation fixed.

**Update** – This is now fixed [in the documentation](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/).

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced Custom Fields plugin does not implement a `get_image` function. Are you sure it shouldn't be `get_field(image)` instead of `get_image(image)`?

Comment: I copied the ACF cookbook function directly from the Timber documentation. See https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/#gallery-field. I also tried `get_field(image)`, but no luck. It showed the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ACF plugin, you can use below code to get the ACF image:

```
{% for item in block_content.add_services %}
    <img src="{{ item.add_service_logo.url }}" alt="{{ item.add_service_logo.alt}}" >
{% endfor %}
```

*add_services* is for the ACF repeater and *add_service_logo* is used for the image (return as an array).